# i want to run a command in Python which is working perfectly in cmd. tried import os and os.system to do so but with no use

Tags: java, python-2.7, silent-installer

The command is for java installation :

```
"jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature" /L D:\Java\setup.log"
```

Comment: Can you show us your python code with which you have tried to run this command?

Comment: import os
>>> os.system('cd\\D:\\Java\\jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature" /L D:\Java\setup.log')

1

This is the code i wrote and it returns 1 as error

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.
I was adding cd before the path of installable which must be removed. After that the command worked just fine.
New command would be
import os
os.system('D:\Java\jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,SourceFeature" /L D:\Java\setup.log')